# how product images sizes effect bandwith and speed of site

Tags: product-images

we uploaded product images with 400 kb,

when uploading the images, will it use bandwidth of 400 kb or will it take the bandwidth of

what product image size we gave in base and thumbinal width and how it works for zooming .

when the image is zooming, will it take 400 kb bandwidth or only the size of zooming the we set.

please guide me about this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This exactly is not a Magento related question but i will keep it open. Someone with better server experience can answer

Comment: I see there is a slight difference in your question compared to this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58933/decrease-the-download-size-of-an-product-image but I think it would be better to describe your problem as a whole to get the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While server side compression and caching are essential I would also recommend to upload already lossless compressed images. Therefore I use this services:

http://www.jpegmini.com/

https://tinypng.com/

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the uploaded image is what gets served i.e. if you upload a 400kb image that it what will be transferred, unless of course you use server size compression like enabling gzip. It is for this reason that poorer quality images do not magnify too well.

Comment: how about downloading 400kb image files. can we reduce the size of those images? if so how?

Comment: If it's compressed server side it will be smaller than 400kb otherwise not. There are a few web based compression service like smush.it . I had a similar scenario and decided to use CDN.