# Decrease the download size of an product image

Tags: product, product-images

you can use inspect element to see product image source and download the images .

the sizes of image are more than 400 kb.

I want to reduce the size of the image.

media.phtml =http://pastebin.com/QBVrCu2X

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Resize function in magento like;

```
$_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
    ->resize($width, $height);
```

```
<img src="<?php echo $_imageUrl; ?>" />
```

or use the bellow extension allows you to optimize all the images in your site, also you can Schedule your Optimization.

- http://gtmetrix.com/magento-optimization-guide.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gtspeed.html

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. can you please tell me in which file, i have to add this code?

and for zooming images can we make it lesser download size?

means if you click on "view larger" or "+" image, it will load big image....

Comment: See app/design/frontend/Your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml                <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):
        $_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                          ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())   ->keepFrame(false)
          ->constrainOnly(true)
                          ->resize(1200);?>
    <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>"
         class="gallery-image"
         src="<?php echo $_imageUrl; ?>"
         data-zoom-image="<?php echo  $_imageUrl; ?>" />
<?php    $i++;    endforeach;?>

Comment: but it's not our theme media.phtml => http://pastebin.com/Sd2emcu9

are you sure the zooming image will take 1200 size in magento 1.9.9 version?

Comment: dont know more about but try this;                            Example Size: 265 x 265 pixels (without zoom)
Example Size: 1100 x 1100 pixels (with zoom)

Comment: please visit this link : http://demo.kidsdial.com/boys-toys/bikes-trikes-ride-ons/toysbox-mind-builder-construction-set-37-models-44-pcs.html

on botttom right of the image there is "+" image, if you click on that real product image will open.

is it possible to decrease the size of that image?

Comment: ,please see updated media.phtml file in question & tell me what i done is correct?

Comment: ,your solution is working for gallery images.... but i need for lightbox images.... 

it's wroking for gallery images : http://demo.kidsdial.com/boys-toys/bikes-trikes-ride-ons/peacock-kinder-blocks-play-set.html

i need for lightbox image, 


please click on the image on "products view page" -http://demo.kidsdial.com/boys-toys/bikes-trikes-ride-ons/peacock-kinder-blocks-play-set.html

it displaying origianl size of image.

I want to restrict that image to 1200.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

@jason's answer is entirely correct, you probably just need to add the 'resize' part to your template where it pulls through the hi-res 'thumbnail'.

Obviously there is more than one way to do anything. You can just set the web server to only serve images of a certain size (or smaller), with it dynamically resizing and optimising anything it finds.

Add Google's Pagespeed Module to your server and configure it to just work on your images for now. The instructions for that are here:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize

This entry is particularly worth the read for where you are:

ImageResolutionLimitBytes

The advantage of the Pagespeed way is that you don't have to manually worry about uploading the correct size images or making sure your templates are behaving. You can just let Pagespeed sort it out and you can then focus on developing other aspects of your site.

Comment: please visit this link : http://demo.kidsdial.com/boys-toys/bikes-trikes-ride-ons/toysbox-mind-builder-construction-set-37-models-44-pcs.html

on botttom right of the image there is "+" image, if you click on that real product image will open.

is it possible to decrease the size of that image?

Comment: Find this in your templates: `<a id="zoom-btn" rel="lightbox[em_lightbox]" href="http://demo.kidsdial.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/s/cs-box.jpg" title="Toysbox Mind Builder construction set 37 models, 44 pcs" class="hoverZoomLink">Zoom</a>` and edit it with @Amit's code for doing a resize.

Comment: hi Woolfie are you speaking about @jason code.

Comment: More precisely: http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/20144/jason-statham

Comment: ,please see updated media.phtml file in question & tell me what i done is correct?

Comment: This lacks the resize, there could be more: `<a id="zoom-btn" rel="lightbox[em_lightbox]" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel());?>">Zoom</a>`

Comment: you are right, seems we have modify that line only, can you please help me to fix the height and width for that....

Answer (score 1):

Why not run your image folder thru Photoshop and resize/optimize the images. Drop them back in your media folder and be done with it? Batch process your images to a smaller/progressive format and use a standard image size like 900x900 or whatever for your future images. Irfranview is a free alternative that can batch process. Your images are 400kb because they are huge and not optimized.

Comment: means, i have to reisze every image individually, am i right?

Comment: No. Batch process your entire product media folder. You can run thousands of images at a time. Just a couple links. With a little research you can probably find more updated instructions. 

http://lifehacker.com/345755/batch-resize-images-with-irfanview

http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-batch-resize-in-photoshop/

In the future its good practice to optimize/size your images before taking them live on your site.

As always. Have a backup. =-p

Answer (score 1):

Instead of resizing each image individually, you will get more benefit from making sure you are serving the right image.  Eg when to use Spriting, PNG, JPG and others.

It is possible to do this manually or to automate the browser optimization and quality globally using a image processing platform.

If you automatically serve WEBP images instead of JpG to chrome users and JPG XR images to Internet explorer- you gain an immediate benefit of up to 50%-80% reduction in size.   Adding in a CDN will also give a lot of advantages and make the images faster.

If you share the url - then I am happy to give specific advise.

Otherwise here is a case study - that might be useful: http://www.magecloud.net/blog/a-case-study-speed-up-magento-pages-by-over-50-with-automatic-image-processing/